How to make incsearch refresh when leaving command window?
With the incsearch option, vim highlights search matches before I leave the search command line. For example, I may perform /abc, and vim shows me all matches for abc although I have not pressed Enter.
In the command line, one can use <C-f> to open the command window and edit the command line using normal mode, and go back to the command line via <C-c>. When one just leaves the command window, the incsearch results don't refresh.
For example, my search command line may contain interesting-text, and vim highlights all matches for interesting-text, and I navigate to the command window to change that to interesting, and go back to the command line, but vim is still showing the matches for interesting-text. Only when I do something (e.g. type a space and delete it), does vim show results for interesting instead.
How can I fix this?

I don't see anything broken, here.

@romainl Do you mean you don't consider this behaviour broken, or that you don't see this behaviour occurring?

I meant the former.

You could add the following mapping that emulate the behavior you have:
nnoremap <expr> <C-c> getbufinfo(bufnr())[0].command ? "<C-c><Space><Bs>" : "<C-c>"

Or as suggested to support also Visual and Insert mode:
noremap <expr> <C-c> getbufinfo(bufnr())[0].command ? "<C-c><Space><Bs>" : "<C-c>"
inoremap <expr> <C-c> getbufinfo(bufnr())[0].command ? "<C-c><Space><Bs>" : "<C-c>"

If you hit Ctrl C in a command window the mapping map it to Ctrl CSpaceBackspace.

Okay, it does work. I assume <expr><C-c> is meant to be separated. The backslashes should also be unnecessary here, since mappings interpret key sequences already.

@user22476690 That sounds right to me, though if you convert to a function you have to use backslashes in double-quoted strings to turn the strings into keys

You are right, it can be made more compact. I have followed your suggestions :-)

Since it is also possible to be in the visual or insert modes in the command window, and move to the command line by <C-c>, probably it would be good to define not just nnoremap but also noremap, noremap! as well.

Thanks for the suggestion, you are right indeed. I have updated the answer accordingly.
